# Problem to view forms registration for anonymous user

Tags: forms, user-interface

I'm using WordPress and Civicrm.
I can see user registration when I am logged in but not when I am an anonymous visitor.

Thank you, I'm a French user.

Comment: hi - did you manage to fix the issue ? this looks like a PHP error

Comment: not the problem still exists .
what version of PHP for cicicrm ?

Comment: it's good when I check in Wordpress Access Control
CiviCRM: skip IDS check 
IDS system is bypassed for users with this permission. Prevents false errors for admin users.

Comment: is that this is a problem for site security ?

Comment: is their anyway you can provide a public page so i can test it ?

Comment: not for the moment, I aml in local. tomorrow I put on provider. thank's

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide access to the guest user/visitor and you can find all the permission in WordPress Access Control

CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Access Control

For more reference please give a read 
https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: thank's but I do that and it's the same thong.

Comment: can you please share some screen shots please

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the `Config.IDS.ini` file is malformed.  That file should get recreated if it doesn't exist - so go ahead and make a backup, then delete the file.

Answer (score -1):

[image: error message anonymous visitor]
[image]

two screens
* URL for the one : localhost/wordpress_sauv/index.php?smartyDebug=1
* URl for the two : localhost/wordpress_sauv/2016/06/10/bonjour-tout-le-monde/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1